# Differentiate radio buttons in css, I cannot differentiate two different radio buttons

Tags: html, image, css, radio-button

I have one set of radio buttons in my registry page, coded as:

```
<label for="text"><input type="radio" name="gen" id='gender' value="Male"> Male <input type="radio" name="gen" id='gender' value="Female"> Female </label><br/>
```

These display standard radio buttons.

I have another set of radio buttons in my quiz page, code

```
<div class='checkoutform'>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<$whatever;$i++){
        if($i==0){
            echo "<div class='fieldlist'>";
            echo "<input class='checkedBox2' name='".$question["id"]."' type='radio' id='shipadd1'>";
            echo "<label for='shipadd1'>";
            echo $contents.'</label>';
            echo "</div>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<div class='fieldlist'>";
            echo "<input type='radio' id='shipadd$j' name='".$question["id"]."'>";
            echo "<label for='shipadd$j'>";
            echo "</div><br/>";
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

The problem is that the second set of radio buttons display the image I want + the standard radio button, i'm finding it hard to differentiate the two. If you could help that would be great. Here is the current css i'm using for both sets of radio buttons:

```
.fieldlist{width:100%; background-color:#fffcd9}

input[type="radio"] + label{
background: url(/images/1.png) right center no-repeat;
background-size: 20px; 
height: 25px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 49px 0 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
    background-size: 20px; -moz-background-size: 20px;
    background: url(/images/2.png) right center no-repeat;
}

label[for=shipadd1]{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

label[for=shipadd2]{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

label[for=shipadd3]{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

label[for=shipadd4]{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
text-align: left;
}
```

So, i'm trying to use the standard radio buttons on one page, wipe the actual radio buttons and replace them to use on a second page. Can someone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you intentionally applying all the css to the labels or do you want it to apply to to the radio buttons?

Answer (score 1):

you have the two radio buttons with the same id

```
id='gender'
```

just try tu put them unique as

```
id='genderMale'            id='genderFemale'
```

Then you have them differentiated per id, not sure if that is what you asked for...

EDIT

What you are doing is bad coding, As I said, different ids and a shared class...

Comment: nah, i need to differentiate the set of gender radio buttons and the shipadd(1,2,3,4) radio buttons

Comment: the id property is suppoused to be unique, so maybe you should differentiate them through a class instead of through id, but as you wish

Answer (score 1):

Add common class for first 2 radio button. Another class for second set. This way you could differentiate them.